# Upload directly to Amazon S3 using Plupload HTML5 runtime

Tags: html, upload, amazon-s3, cors, plupload

I saw in one a previous post [How do I make Plupload upload directly to Amazon S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639471/how-do-i-make-plupload-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3), that this is possible to direct upload from Pluplod Html5 runtime to S3.

I tried your approach by hosting my "pluploader" into my S3 bucket but i am still receiving error from amazon

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxxxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/. Origin http://s3.amazonaws.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Is there someone thar can help me ? Thanks

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639471/how-do-i-make-plupload-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE**:  Amazon S3 now supports Cross-Origin Resource Sharing so HTML5 uploads should now be possible.  See the docs here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html and the original post here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=377271#377271

---

Sorry, but Amazon **still** does not support HTML5 uploads because they do not support the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.  It's been 2 years and there is still no progress from Amazon in regard to this issue.

The old method of hosting an iframe form in your bucket only works for HTML4 uploads, *not* with HTML5.

More info here:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=34281

Also, more info from the Plupload guys here:
http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?pid=2361#p2361

---

If you want to upload a file to S3 using a standard file input field, I would recommend reading this tutorial... otherwise you'll have to use Flash, Silverlight, etc. to upload.

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1

Comment: Looks like S3 just changed today to support CORS headers: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=377271#377271

Comment: @McKAMEY Thanks for updating!  I've updated the answer to reflect this

Comment: Does anyone have any insight into correctly configuring the 'html5' plupload runtime to push directly to s3? Amazon added CORS support, but I have yet to successfully push files to S3 using the 'html5' runtime.

Comment: @njebert - yes,here:

https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/wiki/Upload-to-Amazon-S3"