# Upload files to Amazon using PlUpload and Expiring Amazon S3 Link

Tags: php, amazon-s3, file-upload, plupload

I got plupload working directly to Amazon S3 with [this](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/examples/jquery/s3.php) sample code.I got the [Direct Browser to S3 Upload](https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/direct-browser-s3-upload-example) using temporary credentials.

Now I need to **generate  expiring Amazon S3 Link** and using those temporary credentials need to **implement the Plupload**. ie I need to mix both the cases mentioned above.So I generate the url and put it as the url in the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#uploader").plupload({
    runtimes : 'flash,silverlight',
    url : 'TEMPORARY URL',
    max_file_size : '10mb',

    multipart: true,
    multipart_params: {
        'key': '${filename}', 
        'Filename': '${filename}',
        'acl': 'public-read',
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
        'success_action_status': '201'
    },
    file_data_name: 'file',
    multiple_queues: true,
    filters : [
        {title : "JPEG files", extensions : "jpg"}
    ],
    flash_swf_url : '../../js/plupload.flash.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url : '../../js/plupload.silverlight.xap'
});
});
</script>
```

Generate Expiring Amazon S3 Link

```
<?php 
$S3_KEY='S3 Key Here';
$S3_SECRET='S3 Secret Here';
$S3_BUCKET='/uploadtestbucket';

$EXPIRE_TIME=(60 * 5); // 5 minutes
$S3_URL='http://s3.amazonaws.com';

$objectName='/' . $_GET['name'];

$mimeType=$_GET['type'];
$expires = time() + $EXPIRE_TIME;
$amzHeaders= "x-amz-acl:public-read";
$stringToSign = "PUT\n\n$mimeType\n$expires\n$amzHeaders\n$S3_BUCKET$objectName";
$sig = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $stringToSign, $S3_SECRET, true)));

$url = urlencode("$S3_URL$S3_BUCKET$objectName?    AWSAccessKeyId=$S3_KEY&Expires=$expires&Signature=$sig");

echo $url;
?>
```

But I am getting this error

> IO error. 
>   Error #2032

My reference links are

- [How do I make Plupload upload directly to Amazon S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639471/how-do-i-make-plupload-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3)
- [Upload directly to Amazon S3 using Plupload HTML5 runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463694/upload-directly-to-amazon-s3-using-plupload-html5-runtime)

What is the mistake in my code??

Answer (score 1):

Check your policy, maybe its not setup properly and you are sending "extra inputs". Try using your browser's console and switch to Network panel - find the http request made to amazon and check response, it will show you the error.