# How to upload file of unlimited size to Amazon S3 with plupload?

Tags: video, file-upload, amazon-s3, plupload

Does it support "gluing" files on S3? If not, is it possible to upload several chunks as separate files then? (and later emulate "gluing" via an intermediate server)

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4639529/1236044 it does not seem possible "S3 does not understand chunks, so remove the chunk_size config option."

Comment: I see, thanks. Probably I'll have to solve it via some proxy.